# Twitter's bootstrap stripped down version that works with jquery-file-upload

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

i'm looking for a stripped down version of Twitter's Bootstrap for my website the problem with the original version is:

- interfere with the current CSS styles
- Twitter Bootstrap is giant and mounstrous (but clean) CSS
- i really don't need that works in IE6 IE7

trying to strip down by myself looks like a titanic task and i'm not sure if can i keep all the changes needed, also i can try to do it again if anyone can bring me more ideas how to do it more easly.

**The concrete question is:** there are somewhere in the internet a stripped version of twitter bootstrap that is tailor made to work with Jquery-upload-file without everything else that offer the toolkit?

if such thing doesn't exists i'm open to suggestion to make this task more bereable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own customized version of bootstrap using their on-line [tool](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html), otherwise you'd need to tweak and re-compile the css using [less](http://lesscss.org/).